# google datastore many to one references

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

So i have two model classes:

```
class Dog(db.model):
   dogName = StringProperty()
   dogBreed = StringProperty()

class Cat(db.model):
   catName = StringProperty()
   catBreed = StringProperty()
```

and then i have a third model class to hold all the pictures

```
class Images(db.model):
  imageReference = ReferenceProperty(*Animal*, collection_name = 'allImages')
  imageURL = StringProperty()
```

*Animal* is either a Dog or a Cat.  Obviously this does not compile.

Now my question is:  Is there a way I can put Cat pictures in with Dog pictures?  Or do I need to create more models like this:

```
class DogImages(db.model):
  imageReference = ReferenceProperty(Dog, collection_name = 'allImages')
  imageURL = StringProperty()
class CatImages(db.model):
  imageReference = ReferenceProperty(Cat, collection_name = 'allImages')
  imageURL = StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html):

```
class Animal(polymodel.PolyModel):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  breed = db.StringProperty()

class Dog(Animal):
  pass

class Cat(Animal):
  pass
```

Now you can have a ReferenceProperty that references Animals, and either Dogs or Cats will be permitted.

However, you don't have any properties that are specific to each type of animal - why not just have a regular Animal model, add a property indicating what species it is, and skip the separate models entirely?

Comment: Dog and Cat are just toy examples i made up.  In reality, the models have many attributes and a lot of them are different.  So I dont know if this is something I would want to use.

Comment: @scifirocket In that case, you may have a good use-case for Polymodel. In future, though, it helps if your toy examples reflect the issues that inform your decision in your real code. :)

Comment: You're right.  Polymodels seem to be the perfect match for what I'm looking for.  Thanks!